# Why is still possible to cast all types of variable to "any" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, any

I am still adapting coding using typescript. I am a full stack developer, used with C#, an OOP language. I really don't like dynamic typed languages, and fortunately I still dont have to work with any yet.

I just realized how bad is "any" casting, specially for begginers and people not used with OOP. I mean, it's ok to a generic method to return an any value - at least I can handle with it -, such as retrieving data with axios, rxjs or from local storage, for example, because they're type can really vary.

But what is really annoying me that this is illegal:

```
class C1 {id: string}
class C2 {num: number}

const c1 = new C1()
const c2: C2 = c1;
```

But this for typescript is totally ok:

```
class C1 {/*...*/}
class C2 {/*...*/}

const c1 = new C1();
const c2: C2 = c1 as any;
```

The app I am currently developing has a bunch of these castings, and often when I refact anything, this causes a lot of trouble, creates bugs, etc.

This is totally nonsene, it's just like "Oh, an error? Let me cast "any". Works " and BOOM! The bomb was set

Can someone explain to me if is there any real utility for this possibility?

I actually agree with the OOP, that when we create a generic method, we must set a type, when we declare the function or method - I know, in C# there is the object type, but that is really rare and highly not recommended to use -, and TS has the exactaly same functionality:

```
// C# E.g.:
public T GenericMethod<T>() {
  //...
}

var c1 = GenericMethod<C1>();

// TS E.g.:
genericMethod<T>() {}
// or even
genericMethod = <T>() => ({} as T);
```

This standard is really helpful for getting data from DB Contexts, localStorage, axios, etc, and its easier to handle the possible exceptions

Comment: `any` exists as a concession to the fact that many typescript projects start as javascript projects. `any` is the type that plain javascript variables have. Ie, it basically turns off all typechecking. So yeah, asserting that something is an "any" makes everything allowed, because it's the way you tell typescript "stop checking types now".

Comment: [Type assertions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and [`any`](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) allow developers to *circumvent* the type system and do things they think are okay but which the compiler cannot verify as safe. They should be used sparingly but they are sometimes unavoidable. TS intentionally allows some unsafe things for the sake of convenience (see discussion in [ms/TS#9825](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825)).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

> I just realized how bad is "any" casting

I'm right there with you. I've gotten the nickname "The Any Police" due to the fact that i basically never let one pass through code review.

`any` exists for a specific purpose: To make adoption of typescript easier. Especially in the early days, it was quite common for a codebase to start in javascript and then get converted to typescript piece by piece. `any` is the type that plain javascript variables have, and typescript does not perform type checking on them, except in cases where it can infer the type. The intention is that codebases will start off with many `any`'s, and overtime replace them with real types.

Once a codebase is entirely or primarily in typescript, `any`'s hold it back. They disable typechecking (by design), so they will allow mistakes to slip by, such as the ones you mentioned. On rare occasion they can be useful for telling typescript "trust me, i know what i'm doing, so don't check me here", but they should be avoided. Unfortunately, it looks like the codebase you're inheriting doesn't have The Any Police to keep it in check.

---

PS, while doing `as X` is sometimes referred to as "type casting", it's better to call it and think of it as a "type assertion". You are asserting to typescript "trust me, this is the type". Nothing actually changes at runtime, so if the assertion was a mistake and it's not actually that type, typescript can't help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I laugth a lot with the "The Any Police" haha that was awesome. But seems aweful that the typescript is failing in code safety for beeing begginer friendly. That may cause sever bugs for companies, resulting in money loss. Isn't there any official form to vote for this "functionality" to end?

Comment: There is basically 0 chance they will change it. It is deliberate, and i think ease of adoption is one of the main reasons typescript has grown in popularity as much as it has. What i would recommend is to opt in to using typescript in a strict way. More specifically, i recommend turning on [strict mode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict), and using [a lint rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/) to forbid use of `any`.